# conditional keeping of rows

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

This is part of my file (with 10000 lines):

```
N N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N R N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
A N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N G N N
```

I want to remove those lines where all genotypes are `N` and keep only those lines which have at least 1 non-N genotype. This is my desired output:

```
N N N N R N N N N N N
A N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N G N N
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use the revert grep with the -v option. It will only work on text formatted as in your example but it might be enough for your needs.

```
$ grep -v "N N N N N N N N N N N" yourFile.txt
```

as your request for lines with one genotype different than N, you can create a script containing :

```
#!/bin/sh
while read i
do
        n=`echo $i | tr " " "\n" | uniq -c | grep "N" | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ "$n" == "10" ]
        then
                echo $i
        fi
done < "$1"
```

then give execution rights to your script :

```
$ chmod +x myScript.sh
```

and then run it

```
$ ./myScript.sh myFile.txt
```

Then you can turn around how many N you want on your line modifying

> if [ "$n" == "10" ]

Not very elegant but it does the job and doesn't require anything

Comment: Thanks @M4rty, I did not know it could be that much easy, Is there also ay way that I could keep only those rows with 1 non-N genotype? so I have one row N N N A  A N N and another row N N N N N N A. So I want to keep the second one?

Comment: not as easily, I'll take a look tomorrow but I'm sure someone will answer until then

Comment: @Anna1364 I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks so much, yes it is doing exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/[^N ]/p' input.txt
```

This command checks, does the line contain something except 'N' or ' ' (space). If contains - it prints this line.

Or

```
sed '/[^N ]/!d' input.txt
```

The same result, but by another way - it delete lines containing only 'N' and ' ' (spaces). If the line contains something else - doesn't delete it.

Comment: Or `sed '/^[N ][N ]*$/d' input.txt`, or `sed -E '/^[N ]+$/d' input.txt`, or....

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -alne 'print if grep { $_ ne "N" } @F' file
N N N N R N N N N N N
A N N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N G N N
```

In scalar context, the `grep` evaluates true if there is at least one element of field array `@F` that is not equal to `"N"`.

If you want to test for a specific number of non-N entries, you can do easily - for example, to print only lines with exactly one non-N field:

```
perl -alne 'print if (grep { $_ ne "N" } @F) == 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret the "keep only those lines which has at least 1 non-N (character)" requirement into one of these two grep statements:

1. `grep '[^N ]' input` -- this tells grep to look for lines that contain a character *other than* space or capital-N.
2. `grep -xFv 'N N N N N N N N N N N' input` -- this tells grep to look for lines that are not (`-v`) *completely* (`-x`) made up of the given (fixed/static `-F`) `N ...N` text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`. Skip Empty/Whitespaces(Tabs+/Spaces)/Only N's lines and print rest.

```
awk -F'[^N \t]' 'NF>1'
```