# how to keep rows that has a specific string

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

Following [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397311/117549), how can I keep rows with *only one* non-N genotype?

```
A N N A N N A N N N N
N N N C N N N N N N N
N N N N N N G N N N N
N N N T N N N N N N N
G N N N G N N N N N N
C N N C N C N N N N N
```

my desired output:

```
N N N C N N N N N N N
N N N N N N G N N N N
N N N T N N N N N N N
```

Comment: As per my answer to your previous question: `perl -alne 'print if (grep { $_ ne "N" } @F) == 1' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^[N ]*[^N ][N ]*$/p' input.txt
```

Prints lines containing only one non-N character.

Or, the same, but by another way.

```
sed '/[^N ][N ]*[^N ]/d; /^[N ]*$/d' input.txt
```

Firstly, it deletes all lines containing more than one **non-N** character, then deletes lines containing only **N** characters.

Comment: You can also write `grep -v '[^N ].*[^N ]'`

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -x '[N ]*[^N ][N ]*'
```

For one and only one non-N.

```
grep -v '[^N ].*[^N ]'
```

For at most one non-N (also matches on empty lines or lines with only `N`s).

Since the input seems to only contain characters from the portable character set, you may want to fix the locale to C to speed things up (`LC_ALL=C grep...`).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script containing :

```
#!/bin/sh
while read i
do
        n=`echo $i | tr " " "\n" | uniq -c | grep "N" | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ "$n" == "10" ]
        then
                echo $i
        fi
done < "$1"
```

then give execution rights to your script :

```
$ chmod +x myScript.sh
```

and then run it

```
$ ./myScript.sh myFile.txt
```

Then you can turn around how many N you want on your line modifying

> if [ "$n" == "10" ]

Not very elegant but it does the job and doesn't require anything

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`. Skip Empty/Whitespaces(Tabs+/Spaces)/Only N's lines and print rest where only one non-N genotype is seen.

```
awk -F'[^N \t]' 'NF==2'
```

Comment: It can be shortened to this: `awk -F'[^N ]' 'NF==2'`

Answer (score 0):

Another sed answer:

```
sed -n 'h; s/[N ]//g; /^.$/ {g; p}' file
```

or awk

```
awk '
    {
        n=0 
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i != "N") n++ 
            if (n > 1) break
        }
    } 
    n == 1
' file
```